# HashMap how to find out "extra" keys and remove them

Tags: java

Suppose I have a Hashmap object myMap and it contains a set of keys and values,

```
key1, value1
key2, value2
...
...
```

let's say I have 30 keys in total.

Now I am getting a list of keys: `key1, key2....,` say there are 28.

What is the best way to check myMap object and remove keys that are **NOT** in my list of keys? Do I have to iterate thru the hashmap keyset and compare each one in the list?

thanks.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but will [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) work? (If yes, make sure you check the documentation before asking questions :p)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the set of keys from the map.  The set is backed by the map.  Then call retainAll on it.

```
Set<String> keys = myMap.keySet();
keys.retainAll(keyList);
```

Here's the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) on the `keySet` method.

Here's the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) on the `retainAll` method.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `containsKey` method for each key you have, and if the method returns `false`, remove it. Another option is to use `Map#keySet#retainAll`.

Comment: i think you mean returns false, then remove it.

Comment: @75inchpianist *facepalm* true. Corrected it.

Comment: what do you mean by otherwise?

Comment: @eis I wrote the answer without paying full attention and the redaction, (like `entrySet` instead of `keySet`) was certainly lacking. I revamped it.